# Realm select row from 0 to 20

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-recyclerview, realm

I have 100 elements in my database. I want to initially select the first 20 elements and show it in recyclerview. My goal is to increase this by 20 in the recyclerView load more event. I know how to catch load more events in recyclerView ,but I don't know how to increase select element from table in load more action.

I have written a function which can select all the elements:

```
    public void getTransactions(int start,int end)
{
    try {
        CoreApplication.realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        CoreApplication.realm.executeTransaction(realm -> {
            final RealmResults<Transactions> transactions =
                    realm.where(Transactions.class).findAll(); 
            if (transactions != null && transactions.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < transactions.size(); i++) {
                    Log.e("terminalTables", transactions.get(i).getAdditionalText());
                    Log.e("terminalTables", transactions.get(i).getId()+"");

                }
            }
        });


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (CoreApplication.realm!= null) {
            CoreApplication.realm.close();
        }
    }

}
```

How I can rewrite my code to add two options in RealmResults? ( start and end)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution

```
    public void getTransactions(int start, int end) {
    try {
        CoreApplication.realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        CoreApplication.realm.executeTransaction(realm -> {
            final OrderedRealmCollection<Transactions> transactions =
                    realm.where(Transactions.class).between("id", start, start+end).findAll().createSnapshot();
            if (transactions != null && transactions.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < transactions.size(); i++) {
                    Log.e("terminalTables", transactions.get(i).getAdditionalText());
                    Log.e("terminalTables", transactions.get(i).getId() + "");

                }
            }
        });


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (CoreApplication.realm != null) {
            CoreApplication.realm.close();
        }
    }

}
```